# How to pull code which is in develop branch git bub

Tags: github, git-push, git-pull

I am new to GitHub and I am trying to pull code from develop branch (just another branch) from git hub but its download the code from master branch, which command I should use to get the code from develop branch. pls anyone can explain this. thank u

and whenever I tried to push code I will get the error like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFiNm.jpg)

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the exact commands (or steps, if you're using a GUI Git tool) which you performed to get you to this state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [git-pull man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html):

```
git pull [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

and in the examples section:

Merge into the current branch the remote branch next:

```
$ git pull origin next
```

So I imagine you want to do something like:

```
git pull origin dev
```

To set it up so that it does this by default while you're on the dev branch:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to dev origin/dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

`git clone -b <branch> <remote_repo>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify your current remote by doing 
git remote -v 
and you will see to which remote repositories you are pointing your files;
when you are on your develop branch and have made the
git pull origin master 
and
git push -u origin master,
switch to master branch and merge:
git merge myDevelop branch.
Hope it helps.